After SpringBoot upgrade v3.2.3 to v3.2.4 app doesn't start - error Failed to register Collector MicrometerCollector: jvm_info is already in use
After upgrading Spring Bootfrom v3.2.3 to v3.2.4 / v3.2.5 the application doesn't start due to error Failed to register Collector of type MicrometerCollector: jvm_info is already in use by another Collector of type VersionInfoExports.
2024-04-23T15:40:33.927+02:00  WARN 4252 --- [CMF] [           main] ConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Failed to register Collector of type MicrometerCollector: jvm_info is already in use by another Collector of type VersionInfoExports
2024-04-23T15:40:33.928+02:00  INFO 4252 --- [CMF] [           main] SEM-LOG                                  : 23/04/2024 15:40:33~|~303017220~|~N/A~|~N/A~|~uh14zs~|~N/A~|~N/A~|~Process fso on localhost/192.168.1.238 has stopped~|~N/A~|~N/A~|~N/A~|~fso
2024-04-23T15:40:33.936+02:00  INFO 4252 --- [CMF] [           main] .a.t.c.t.h.i.WaitForCloseListeningServer : Stopping Administration endpoint server at /[0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0]:10081
2024-04-23T15:40:33.941+02:00  INFO 4252 --- [CMF] [           main] .a.t.c.t.h.i.WaitForCloseListeningServer : Administration endpoint stopped
2024-04-23T15:40:33.942+02:00  WARN 4252 --- [CMF] [Netty 4 Timer-1] c.i.a.m.a.probe.ProbeRegistry            : ReadinessProbe Spring-Context-Initialized failed
2024-04-23T15:40:33.942+02:00  WARN 4252 --- [CMF] [Netty 4 Timer-1] c.i.a.m.a.probe.ProbeRegistry            : ReadinessProbe WarmupExecutingProbe failed
2024-04-23T15:40:33.945+02:00  WARN 4252 --- [CMF] [           main] o.s.b.f.support.DisposableBeanAdapter    : Invocation of close method failed on bean with name 'tracer': java.lang.AbstractMethodError: Receiver class io.opentracing.util.GlobalTracer does not define or inherit an implementation of the resolved method 'abstract void close()' of interface java.lang.AutoCloseable.
2024-04-23T15:40:33.951+02:00  INFO 4252 --- [CMF] [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Stopping service [Tomcat]
2024-04-23T15:40:33.955+02:00  WARN 4252 --- [CMF] [           main] o.a.c.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase       : The web application [fso] appears to have started a thread named [Timer-0] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak. Stack trace of thread:
 java.base/java.lang.Object.wait0(Native Method)
 java.base/java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:366)
 java.base/java.util.TimerThread.mainLoop(Timer.java:563)
 java.base/java.util.TimerThread.run(Timer.java:516)
2024-04-23T15:40:33.973+02:00  INFO 4252 --- [CMF] [           main] .s.b.a.l.ConditionEvaluationReportLogger : 

Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the condition evaluation report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2024-04-23T15:40:33.987+02:00 ERROR 4252 --- [CMF] [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed

java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Failed to register Collector of type MicrometerCollector: jvm_info is already in use by another Collector of type VersionInfoExports
    at io.prometheus.client.CollectorRegistry.register(CollectorRegistry.java:57)
    at io.prometheus.client.Collector.register(Collector.java:307)
    at io.micrometer.prometheus.PrometheusMeterRegistry.lambda$applyToCollector$18(PrometheusMeterRegistry.java:581)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap.compute(ConcurrentHashMap.java:1955)
    at io.micrometer.prometheus.PrometheusMeterRegistry.applyToCollector(PrometheusMeterRegistry.java:576)
    at io.micrometer.prometheus.PrometheusMeterRegistry.newGauge(PrometheusMeterRegistry.java:334)
    at io.micrometer.core.instrument.MeterRegistry.lambda$gauge$4(MeterRegistry.java:324)
    at io.micrometer.core.instrument.MeterRegistry.lambda$registerMeterIfNecessary$8(MeterRegistry.java:583)
    at io.micrometer.core.instrument.MeterRegistry.getOrCreateMeter(MeterRegistry.java:638)
    at io.micrometer.core.instrument.MeterRegistry.registerMeterIfNecessary(MeterRegistry.java:590)
    at io.micrometer.core.instrument.MeterRegistry.registerMeterIfNecessary(MeterRegistry.java:583)
    at io.micrometer.core.instrument.MeterRegistry.gauge(MeterRegistry.java:324)
    at io.micrometer.core.instrument.Gauge$Builder.register(Gauge.java:195)
    at io.micrometer.core.instrument.binder.jvm.JvmInfoMetrics.bindTo(JvmInfoMetrics.java:38)
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.metrics.MeterRegistryPostProcessor.lambda$applyBinders$1(MeterRegistryPostProcessor.java:149)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp$OfRef.accept(ForEachOps.java:183)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1511)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.SortedOps$RefSortingSink.end(SortedOps.java:395)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.Sink$ChainedReference.end(Sink.java:258)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.Sink$ChainedReference.end(Sink.java:258)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:510)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:499)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp.evaluateSequential(ForEachOps.java:150)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp$OfRef.evaluateSequential(ForEachOps.java:173)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.forEach(ReferencePipeline.java:596)
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.metrics.MeterRegistryPostProcessor.applyBinders(MeterRegistryPostProcessor.java:149)
    at java.base/java.lang.Iterable.forEach(Iterable.java:75)
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.metrics.MeterRegistryPostProcessor.afterSingletonsInstantiated(MeterRegistryPostProcessor.java:92)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:986)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:962)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:624)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:146)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:754)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:456)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:334)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1354)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1343)
    at nl.ing.cbp.fso.FsoApplicationKt.main(FsoApplication.kt:20)



Main program:
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication
import org.springframework.boot.builder.SpringApplicationBuilder
import org.springframework.boot.runApplication
import org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.SpringBootServletInitializer

@SpringBootApplication
class FsoApplication : SpringBootServletInitializer() {
    override fun configure(builder: SpringApplicationBuilder): SpringApplicationBuilder {
        return builder.sources(FsoApplication::class.java)
    }
}

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    @Suppress("SpreadOperator")
    runApplication<FsoApplication>(*args)
}


Does anyone have an idea what the cause of this problem could be and how to solve this?

Looks like two processes are trying to use jvm_info.
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Failed to register Collector of type MicrometerCollector: jvm_info is already in use by another Collector of type VersionInfoExports

You need to turn off one.  To turn off VersionInfoExports  try adding this in applications.properties files.
management.metrics.enable.process.files=false


Thank you for your reply! I tried your solution, but I still get the same error.

We found a workaround solution by adding the following bean to the application configuration:
@Bean
fun meterRegistryCustomizer(meterRegistry: MeterRegistry): MeterRegistryCustomizer<MeterRegistry> {
    meterRegistry.config().namingConvention { name, type, baseUnit -> name }
    return MeterRegistryCustomizer { registry ->
        registry.config().namingConvention { name, type, baseUnit -> name }
    }
}

Which causes the following circular reference:
>  webMvcObservationFilter defined in class path resource
> [org/springframework/boot/actuate/autoconfigure/observation/web/servlet/WebMvcObservationAutoConfiguration.class]
>       ↓    observationRegistry defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/actuate/autoconfigure/observation/ObservationAutoConfiguration.class]
>       ↓    defaultMeterObservationHandler defined in class path resource
> [org/springframework/boot/actuate/autoconfigure/observation/ObservationAutoConfiguration$MeterObservationHandlerConfiguration$OnlyMetricsMeterObservationHandlerConfiguration.class]
> ┌─────┐ |  merakPrometheusRegistry defined in class path resource
> [com/ing/apisdk/merak/autoconfigure/metrics/prometheus/PrometheusAutoConfiguration.class]
> ↑     ↓ |  meterRegistryCustomizer defined in class path resource [nl/ing/cbp/fso/config/FSOBeanConfiguration.class] 
> └─────┘

After breaking the cycle with spring.main.allow-circular-references set to true, the application started successfully.

This does not break the cycle just ignores it. The problem is still there. It seems you custom config causes this in com.ing.apisdk.merak.autoconfigure.metrics.prometheus.PrometheusAutoConfiguration what if you delete it? Why do you need it?
